# Need to fit a logo in relative-layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am working with a new android application. Now i need to fit a logo in the bottom right corner here i am using relative layout as the parent.So it is difficult to me please some one help me to fix this.
**Picture**
[image: My need is to fix the red logo above the progress-bar and bottom right of the window as shown in the picture]

Comment: Check the answer as correct if did help u, in order to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use layout_alignParentBottom attribute in your ImageView too, since views are positioned by default in the top left corner in relative layouts.

Comment: @Daniel: In this case, no need. It is inheriting that attribute from the `@+id/progressBar`.

Answer (score 3):

You could easily do this by using something like this:

.....

```
<ImageView
android:id = "@+id/logo"
android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
android:src = "@drawable/logo"
/>
```

Comment: but it showing an error like  - [Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentBottom' in package 'android'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentRight' in package 'android'

Comment: I edited my answer, use layout_alignParentBottom and layout_alignParentRight instead. The missing content description is just a warning from lint.